# Concat string and Value in SQL

Tags: sql

Please I need your help, I want to concatenate variable and string :
below my code :

```
DECLARE @startTS datetime2(3) = DATEADD(MI, -20, GETDATE())
DECLARE  @param nvarchar(max), @runID char(36) , @isDelta char(1)

SET @param = '{"SourceDatabase":"DWH", "SourceSchema":"dbo","SourceTable":"LU_ERs","TargetDatabase":"ADrS","TargetSchema":"ofr","TargetTable":"LU_ERs"'+',"isDelta":"' + CAST(@isDelta AS nvarchar(1)) + '","startTS":"' + CAST(@startTS AS nvarchar(50)) + '"}'

SELECT @param
```

I get back NULL.

I want to get something like this :

```
{
    "SourceDatabase": "DWH",  
    "SourceSchema": "dbo",
    "SourceTable": "LU_ERs",
    "TargetDatabase": "ADrS",
    "TargetSchema": "ofr",
    "TargetTable": "LU_ERs",
    "isDelta": "1",
    "startTS":"2023-04-10 16:04:30.493" 
}
```

I specify this

```
{
    "SourceDatabase": "DWH",  
    "SourceSchema": "dbo",
    "SourceTable": "LU_ERs",
    "TargetDatabase": "ADrS",
    "TargetSchema": "ofr",
    "TargetTable": "LU_ERs"
```

comes another variable.

Comment: You didn't initialize a value for @isDelta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL SERVER then try this :

```
SET @param = '{"SourceDatabase":"DWH", "SourceSchema":"dbo","SourceTable":"LU_ERs","TargetDatabase":"ADrS","TargetSchema":"ofr","TargetTable":"LU_ERs"'+',"isDelta":"' + COALESCE(CAST(@isDelta AS nvarchar(1)),'') + '","startTS":"' + CAST(@startTS AS nvarchar(50)) + '"}'
```

The error is that the `@isDelta` is null, so use `COALESCE` to returns a default value if `@isDelta` is null exemple empty value `''`

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), instead of the old school `+` for string concatenation, the function will handle both your data conversions and your `NULL` issues for you.

```
SET @param = CONCAT(
  '''{"SourceDatabase":"DWH", "SourceSchema":"dbo","SourceTable":"LU_ERs","TargetDatabase":"ADrS","TargetSchema":"ofr","TargetTable":"LU_ERs"'
  ,',"isDelta":"'
  ,@isDelta
  ,'","startTS":"'
  ,@startTS,'"}''');
```

Just substitute a comma for every `+` in your current concatenation, remove your explicit `CAST`s, and let the code do the work for you.

Result:

```
{"SourceDatabase":"DWH", "SourceSchema":"dbo","SourceTable":"LU_ERs","TargetDatabase":"ADrS","TargetSchema":"ofr","TargetTable":"LU_ERs","isDelta":"","startTS":"2023-04-10 14:44:50.863"}
```

Edited to add opening and closing single quotes per comment.

Comment: A single quote has to be escaped with another single quote. I edited the `SET` statement to reflect the opening and closing quotes.